# regex to fix the input string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

my problem is as follows

I read from a file line per line and each line contains this text:

```
126,1,1,1,0,1,0,-0.005,-0.005,0.01,0.01,1.,-1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,       5P      8
-0.005,0.01,0.,0.,1.;                                                  5P      9
```

In a cycle I split each element whenever I find a "," and save it into an array with
                PS[k].ParameterS = PSection[k].Split(',');

Then I try to save each element into a new text file with a tag for example:

```
Element1 = 126
Element2 = 1
```

and so on... My problem is that I need to fix the trucated/incomplete decimal elements, for instance: "1." "0."  "-1." with their proper representation "1.0" "0.0" "-1.0"

I have searched for a long time but I haven't find out if I can use wild cards to be able to fix those elements. for instance to replace the empty spaces I used
    PS[k].ParameterS[l] = PS[k].ParameterS[l].Replace(" ", "");
before doing the split process.

My output so far is just the elements separated by a comma "," but with incomplete decimals.

Comment: What language / platform is this?

Comment: Seems like C#, from the `.Replace()`.

Comment: It's C#, sorry to omit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in a zero between dot and comma/end before splitting:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "\\.(?=;|,|$)", ".0");
```

This effectively inserts a zero between dot and comma/end.

Comment: didn't this will also remove the comma/end?

Comment: @Angga No - I used a look-ahead, which is non-consuming

Comment: This worked but without the replaceALL, I used it as   `string input0 = Regex.Replace(input,"\\.(?=,|$)", ".0");`

Comment: I used this replace as well in order to fix the 0., and the 0.; that happened in other occasions. `LineTempP2 = LineTempP2.Replace("0.,", "0,").Replace("0.;", "0;");`

Comment: No need for two calls to `Replace`: see further edits to regex that now works with semi-colons too

Answer (score 0):

you can replaceAll `(-{0,1}\d+\.)([^\d])` with `$10$2` to fix that problem before or after you do your split

[view my example here](http://regexr.com?35qkn) you can replace that match with firstGroup+"0"+secondGroup

Comment: you need to check that nothing is after the period, also instead of using `{0,1}` just use the optional regex character `?`

Comment: no, he said that his string is in one line, you can't add `$` as the end of string if he do the fixing process first. And yes `?` or `{0,1}` is the same, i just like `{0,1}` cz it's more clearer to see than `?` that used in many occurrence.

Comment: i didn't say to add `$` to the end, there can't be a number after is what i meant.  because if there is then you would be doing the following changing `1.1` to `1.0`.  More specifically in his sample string you'd be taking `0.01` and making it `0.0`